# LMFIT not properly fitting where scipy does with same starting parameter values

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, lmfit

I have a complicated curve fitting function:

```py
def corr_function(tau: np.ndarray, BG: float, avg_C: float, vz: float):
    wxc = 8.3
    wy = 2.5
    wz = 3.35
    D = 4.4e1 
    return 1/((math.pi)**(3/2)*wxc*wy*wz*avg_C)*(1 + 4*D*tau/(wxc**2))**(-1/2)*(1 + 4*D*tau/(wy**2))**(-1/2)*(1 + 4*D*tau/(wz**2))**(-1/2)*np.exp(-((vz*tau)**2/(wz**2 + 4*D*tau))) + BG
```

I tried to fit this with scipy:

```py
popt, pcov = curve_fit(corr_function, tau, corr, [0, 1e-12, 2e5])
```

and lmfit

```py
model = Model(corr_function, independent_vars=['tau'])
result = model.fit(
   corr,
   tau=tau,
   BG=Parameter('BG', value=0, min=0),
   avg_C=Parameter('avg_C', value=1e-12, min=0),
   vz=Parameter('vz', value=2e5, min=0),
)
```

And while the scipy converges to a proper answer (blue), the lmfit doesn't (orange), where lmfit parameters don't change really at all during fitting

```
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 61
    # data points      = 400
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 1.5370e+12
    reduced chi-square = 3.8714e+09
    Akaike info crit   = 8833.74620
    Bayesian info crit = 8845.72059
##  Warning: uncertainties could not be estimated:
    BG_guess:     at boundary
    avg_C_guess:  at initial value
    avg_C_guess:  at boundary
[[Variables]]
    BG:     0.00000000 (init = 0)
    avg_C:  3.9999e-12 (init = 4e-12)
    vz:     8831416.63 (init = 200000)
```

I think I need lmfit to sample a larger parameter space (or more iterations), anyone know how to do this?

[image: graph comparison]

Also, note, I need to the input parameters to be static (can't bring them closer to proper fit), as I'll need to automate fitting for large parameter spaces

Comment: the likely issue is that your bounds (i.e., `min` value) are way to close or identical to your initial guesses. You should only use bounds to make sure the value cannot go to physically impossible values.

Comment: Not a solution, but just as a check: if you give something close to the optimal values computed by `curve_fit` as the initial guess for the lmfit function, does it converge?

Comment: Thanks both of you, I did test with values closer to expected and it worked there... however, given all the headache, I just adapted my Scipy implementation to make it work...

Comment: Don't use an initial value that is at the boundary. The lmfit report is telling you that some of your parameter values are stuck at boundaries.  For sure, having reasonable initial values is important, And that "reasonable" includes that small changes in parameter values will actually have an effect on the fit quality.